# How to change the title of the integrated terminal in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When I launch an application in vscode via launch.json.
The application launches from the integrated terminal with the title of the terminal set to that application name.

How can enforce my choice of name for the terminal? Can I set some attribute in launch.json to achieve this?

[image]

*Note* - Raised a GitHub Feature Request-
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/109235

Comment: Are you aware of the `workbench.action.terminal.renameWithArg` command?  It can't be used in a launch configuration but could be a workaround in the meantime.  Let me know if you want to see how it works.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69430683/836330 for more options on setting default names in the settings.