# Vscode start terminal instance as the project name

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When i start the project it creates instance of terminal with generic name Python and thats all.
Is that possible to adjust, that the terminal window would be named as project file name?
So terminal will be called app.py? (Without renaming it by hand)

Take a look in screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See vscode v1.61
[setting up custom terminal titles and descriptions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_61.md#custom-title-and-description).  You could try changing the title to :

`"terminal.integrated.tabs.title": "${workspaceFolder}"`

in your `settings.json`.

> We now support configuring both title and description to help with
> this using variables described in `terminal.integrated.tabs.title` and
> `terminal.integrated.tabs.description` settings.
>
> The current default values are:

```
{
  "terminal.integrated.tabs.title": "${process}",
  "terminal.integrated.tabs.description": "${task}${separator}${local}${separator}${cwdFolder}"
}
```

Variables available are:

```
${cwd} - The terminal's current working directory  
${cwdFolder} - The terminal's current working directory.  
${workspaceFolder} - The workspace in which the terminal was launched.  
${local} - Indicates a local terminal in a remote workspace.  
${process} - The name of the terminal process.  
${separator} - A conditional separator (" - ") that only shows when surrounded by variables with values or static text.  
${sequence} - The name provided to xterm.js by the process.  
${task} - Indicates this terminal is associated with a task.
```